# How can i configure my .env file to connect 2 different databases in one project in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I have 2 different databases where i am using `MySQL` with 2 different database using `laravel 9`.

The 1st database name as `stores` and 2nd database name as `producers` . I want to use this 2 different database in my one project but I don't know about how my `.env` file is working

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=stores
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=****
```

I have added my first database details in my `.env` file. Now how may I connect 2nd database with it in laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

Create a new DB config in your .env

```
DB_CONNECTION_PRODUCERS=mysql
DB_HOST_PRODUCERS=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_PRODUCERS=3306
DB_DATABASE_PRODUCERS=producers
DB_USERNAME_PRODUCERS=root
DB_PASSWORD_PRODUCERS=****
```

Create a new database connection in config/database.php:

```
'producers' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_PRODUCERS', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_PRODUCERS', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_PRODUCERS', 'producers'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_PRODUCERS', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_PRODUCERS', ''),
],
```

Connect to it in your code like:

```
$producers = DB::connection('producers')->table('table_name')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

@Karl has already provided a helpful answer, but I'd like to emphasize the importance of using the protected $connection property in your model.

```
 `protected $connection = 'other_database';`
```

It's a more elegant way to manage database connections for your specific model, as demonstrated above. This approach helps keep your code organized and maintainable.

I'm posting this as a separate answer since I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I believe this additional information will be valuable to you and other users reading this question.